# Slow Ubuntu 14.04 and freezing applications. Why?

Tags: 14.04, acer

Yesterday I've installed a 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 on my Acer AO722 because I wanted to change from my Win8.

I can't imagine why but it runs slowly. I have to wait a lot for launching an app or just opening my files and about every second window that is sent by something from the system starts freezing (eg. system settings, folder properties...), it gets dark for a while then it comes back and that's when I can start to work with it.

The laptop has 4Gb RAM an AMD C60 dual-core 1.333ghz processor, and an AMD Radeon 6250 i think. In the system settings Ubuntu says "Gallium 0.4 on AMD PALM". The system is on a 100Gb partition.

What can be the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Acer Aspire One 722 netbook has no discrete graphics processor, so your AMD C60 dual-core 1.333GHz processor has to do all the graphics processing using the integrated AMD Radeon HD 6290 graphics processor. Ubuntu's Unity desktop is too heavy for your CPU and it's slowing your operating system down. You would get better performance if you installed an Ubuntu flavor with a lightweight desktop environment, either Xubuntu or Lubuntu. Lubuntu looks clunky like Windows XP, but it is even more lightweight than Xubuntu in case Xubuntu is also too slow.

Because the choice is down to Xubuntu vs. Lubuntu, hopefully someone who has had experience with a similar processor to yours will be able answer the question of whether Xubuntu would run OK on your netbook.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not too happy with that. Anyways it worked great with win8. That doesn't have as "big" system requirement as ubuntu?

Comment: You can compare the systems requirements for Ubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu at this question: [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar). The minimal system requirements for all Ubuntu flavors are rather frugal. Xubuntu will run OK on a computer with a Pentium 4 processor (single core).